# How can I scale down a an object with keyframed animation?

Tags: animation, transforms, baking

I've modelled something that I want to break apart, and used a rigid body simulation to achieve this. Edit: Additionally, the final results have been baked to keyframes.

The issue is that, to get the correct results, I was forced to scale up my original objects. I need to scale everything back down, including the animation.

Creating an empty and parenting my objects to it, then scaling down the empty, ensures everything is the correct size, and that the animation looks correct.

However, when attempting to apply the scale of the objects, the animation 'breaks' and now everything looks wrong.

How can I get the scale I need, while preserving the animations, without needing to keep everything parented to the empty? This is intended for export, so I can't just keep it.

**Edit: I think I figured it out:**

1. Do your simulation. Bake the results to keyframes when satisfied.
2. Parent everything you want to scale to a new empty.
3. Scale to desired size.
4. Select whatever part of your mesh needs to be scaled
5. Bake action. Select 'Visual Keying' and 'Clear Parent'
6. You can now delete the empty as it is not being used
7. Go into the graph editor, then for your mesh or meshes, navigate to "Action Bake"
8. Delete X/Y/Z scale
9. Finally, select your meshes and apply scale. Everything will be 1.1.1 and your animation should be scaled properly

Comment: why do you want to apply the scale?

Comment: The model is intended for a game, and it needs to be at the scale it will appear at in-game when I export it. If this was just for a viewport animation or something, keeping the animation scaled down through the empty would be fine.

In order to get the simulation results I wanted, I had to make everything bigger. I want the final model elements to look how it should be before it was scaled up, with the newly baked animations also scaled down

Comment: did you use rigid body -> apply transforms?

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to mention that the simulation has already been baked to keyframes. I'm not sure where/when I would apply that, at which stage in the workflow?

Comment: I'm not sure about your workflow. If re-baking is an option, do it with apply transforms selected. Otherwise, eg in Unity you can tell an object (fbx) to import at any scale. Maybe that might be the quicker solution

Comment: Alrighty, I think I figured it out. After scaling the objects with the empty, then scaling it down, I rebaked the animations. This time, selecting visual keying, clear parent, overwrite action. After which, I could go into the graph editor and delete the "action bake: x/y/z scale". Then I was able to apply the scale to each element. The animation plays how it should, at the size it should, at 1/1/1 scale. I'll update my question.